# Result Join multiple columns from common ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I am trying to build a view ultimately

I have 2 tables , User name and ID in one transaction posted and modified in another

```
Table A 
ID,Username

Table B 
Date ,User ID , Modified UserID , Created User ID,INVtotal,InVDesc

Select a.Username,Date ,User ID , Modified UserID , Created User ID,INVtotal,InVDesc
   from Table B
   join 
   Table A  on a.ID = User ID
```

The above gives me the result fine but I would like to have the username and not the ID appear in the  Modified UserID , Created User  columns , because these may differ as changes occur.

Thank you

Sample Data

```
ID  Username                
1   May                 
2   Jon             
3   Sam             
4   Eric                

Date      UserID    ModifedUserID   CreatedUserID   INVTotal InVDesc
26/10/2018  1        2                 1             100    A123
26/10/2018  1        3                 1             200    A124
26/10/2018  2        4                 2             100    A125
26/10/2018  2                          2             200    A126
26/10/2018  4        1                 4             100    A127
26/10/2018  3        1                 3             200    A128
```

Expected Result

```
Date        UserID   ModifedUserID  CreatedUserID    INVTotal   InVDesc
26/10/2018  May      Jon            May              100    A123
```

Comment: I think you are looking to self-join. Could you post DDL, Sample data?

Comment: Some sample data and expected output would help to answer!

Comment: could you please provide your expected output and sample data

Comment: Sample data added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are already two solution available by using **JOIN** as above, but I am posting different solution here - by using **FUNCTION**.

Create a user defined function which returns username, based on the provided userid.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ufn_GetUserName (@userID INT)
RETURNS VARCHAR(10)
AS
BEGIN
     DECLARE @username VARCHAR(10) = ''
     SELECT @username = Username FROM TableA WHERE ID = @userID
     RETURN @username
END
```

Use this function to fetch the username of concerned userid. by doing this, you can avoid multiple joins in your query.

```
SELECT 
    DATE,
    dbo.ufn_GetUserName(UserID) AS UserID,
    dbo.ufn_GetUserName(ModifiedUserID) AS ModifiedUserID, 
    dbo.ufn_GetUserName(CreatedUserID) AS CreatedUserID,
    INVtotal,
    InVDesc
FROM TableB
```

Thanks,
Sandy

Comment: Thanks Sandy I love the idea of the function and its very neat and clean , applying it in a view may be tricky but very awesome Thank you I appreciate it .

Comment: I have tried this and it works better than the joins ,seems to be less taxing when used as part of a report ,Thank you

Comment: @Hassan - The method with a function looks good but if you have a lot of data it's most slowly than the method with JOINs.

Answer (score 1):

Hope I understood you correctly

```
SELECT
  b.Date,
  --b.UserID,
  u1.Username,
  --b.ModifiedUserID,
  u2.Username ModifiedUsername,
  --b.CreatedUserID,
  u3.Username CreatedUsername,
  b.INVtotal,
  b.InVDesc
FROM TableB b
JOIN TableA u1 ON b.UserID=u1.ID
LEFT JOIN TableA u2 ON b.ModifiedUserID=u2.ID
LEFT JOIN TableA u3 ON b.CreatedUserID=u3.ID
```

If `b.UserID` can be `NULL` then you need also use `LEFT JOIN` for `TableA u1`.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
CREATE TABLE T1
    ([ID] int, [Username] varchar(4))
;

INSERT INTO T1
    ([ID], [Username])
VALUES
    (1, 'May'),
    (2, 'Jon'),
    (3, 'Sam'),
    (4, 'Eric')
;


CREATE TABLE T2
    ([Date] varchar(10), [UserID] int, [ModifedUserID] int, [CreatedUserID] int, [INVTotal InVDesc] varchar(8))
;

INSERT INTO T2
    ([Date], [UserID], [ModifedUserID], [CreatedUserID], [INVTotal InVDesc])
VALUES
    ('26/10/2018', 1, 2, 1, '100 A123'),
    ('26/10/2018', 1, 3, 1, '200 A124'),
    ('26/10/2018', 2, 4, 2, '100 A125'),
    ('26/10/2018', 2, 2, 200, 'A126'),
    ('26/10/2018', 4, 1, 4, '100 A127'),
    ('26/10/2018', 3, 1, 3, '200 A128')
;

SELECT T1.UserName,
       T11.UserName As ModifiedBy,
       T111.UserName As CreatedBy,
       T2.[Date],
       T2.[INVTotal InVDesc]
FROM T1 INNER JOIN T2 ON T1.ID = T2.UserID
        INNER JOIN T1 T11 ON T2.ModifedUserID = T11.ID
        INNER JOIN T1 T111 ON T2.CreatedUserID = T111.ID
WHERE T2.ModifedUserID = 2;
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for , I love the function idea above but this concept does it exactly.